# Function created using "crypto" won't return the bearerToken I created with it

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I am sure this is something basic that I am missing but it's late and my brain gets like that. So I have this function:

```
export const createRandomHex = () => {
  try {
    return crypto.randomBytes(127, (_err, buf) => {
      console.log("[create] bearerToken: ", buf.toString("hex"));
      const bearerTokenString = buf.toString("hex");
      return bearerTokenString;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
};
```

And I am calling it in another function as such:

```
export const createBearerToken = () => {
    const bearerToken = createRandomHex();
}
```

For some reason, the value of bearerToken in the createBearerToken is undefined or null. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `randomBytes` is async, hence the callback. You might consider returning a promise in `createRandomHex` instead.

Comment: I had a feeling hahahaha thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randomBytes` is asynchronous and takes a callback. You could return a promise in your function:

```js
export const createRandomHex = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      return crypto.randomBytes(127, (_err, buf) => {
        console.log("[create] bearerToken: ", buf.toString("hex"));
        const bearerTokenString = buf.toString("hex");
        resolve(bearerTokenString);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
};
```